# CSS disappears with trail slash

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem right now.

Whenever i have a trailing slash on my url, it leaves it without css.

I read a answer from another post that said that you should use the full url path instead of just `css/style.css` though, that didn't work for me.

[How it looks with trail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZQAp.gif)

I also use `filemtime()` for my css file.

`echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?'.filemtime("css/style.css").'">';`

So how would i go with this?

Comment: what do you mean, trailing slash? `css/style.css/`? That'd tell the browser/server to look for a directory named "style.css". If you mean `/css/style.css`, that's a LEADING slash, not a trailing.

Comment: @MarcB If you look in the link i provided, you see the url at the top of what  happens. I'm using a filemtime() function as i provided in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** First of all as @Marc mentioned, it is leading slash, when you add slash in browser after `index.php/` then browser checks your css file as `urlname.com/index.php/css/style.css`.

**Solution:**

1. Either use full path
2. Use rewrite rule to remove slash to avoid such issue.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
   ```

Comment: The only problem is that when i type index.php/somethingrandom it makes it into a directory looking URL. The Rewrite only worked when it was a normal index.php/ but not if something was typed after it

Comment: This rule is only for leading slash after any page not any directory you type after . This solution applies to problem you asked in question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used a full url like this which solved the problem:

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://urlname.com/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a url which is relative to your root?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?'.filemtime("/css/style.css").'">`

Comment: With the filemtime, it gives me stat failed error when i use that.

Comment: Did you add a leading slash in `filemtime("/css/style.css")` ?

Comment: You can also try prepending $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].